# Is this possible with HTML?

Tags: html, css

I need to implement a menucard in to a website. My customer wants, that it looks exactly like on the card in the restaurant.

Is it with HTML possible to put a border-line directly under the text like on the image below ("Hauptgerichte")? And if yes, how could I realize that?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the border to touch the text, you can adjust the `line-height` to something small:

```
p
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    line-height: 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kz43g/

Comment: Perfectly! I have spend so much time and it is So simple... Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 1):

Here is 1 variant - here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trajce/8ejMr/).
html:

```
 <div>
        <p> some text </p>
    </div>
```

css:

```
*{
padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
div{
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
p{
    margin-bottom:-5px;
}
```

i just put negative bottom margin to the text container (in this case the p tag)

Answer (score 1):

Pure CSS solution is possible with pseudoelement `after`, see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e2w9g/2/). The distance from text is done by the `bottom:3px`:

```
.underline {
    position:relative;
}
.underline::after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 3px;
    left:0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;    
}
```

edit: the line-height solution looks better :)

Answer (score 1):

This is possible in HTML / CSS: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8VuPA/)

HTML:

```
<h3 class="yourClass">Text place</h3>
```

CSS :

```
.yourClass{
   width:300px;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
   text-indent:50px;
   line-height:80%;
}
```

In this example I'm changing the line height to move the text under the line and the then using text-indent to move it to the correct positioning. It should give you the desired results. There are a few ways to do this, but this will require less HTML.

Comment: Thank you. I have to keep that "text-indent"-tag in mind. Really useful!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/orequt/5/) that shows how this could be done. I added a border to the bottom of the paragraph and a little padding to the left. Then I changed the line height of the paragraph so it would sit right on the border.

You could try working with:

```
text-decoration: underline;
```

I choose to use the border property for easy customization.

CSS from JS Bin:

```
p {
  border-bottom:1px solid #333;
  line-height: 50%;
  padding: 0 0 0 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the header in H tags, then target the H tag with CSS and apply border bottom.

HTML

```
<div id="content">
<h1>title</h1>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#content h1{
Border-bottom:1px solid #999;
Width: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the text inside of a div. Then, make the div a set width. Then, add a border to the div.

```
<div id="title">
 <h2> Hauptgerichte </h2>
</div>

/*CSS*/
#title{
  width: 50px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
}
```